# collision detect between a rectangle and a slice of a circle

Tags: python, pyqt, geometry, collision-detection

I made an object with three points of view. one for forward, one for left, and one for right.

[image]

these POVs are some path like a slice of a circle

[image]

I want to detect intersections or collisions between these POVs with rectangles to set the color of each POV

POVs rotate with the object in any direction but rectangles are always oriented

[image]
[image]

here is my code

```
from random import randint
from sys import argv
from PyQt6.QtCore import QRectF, Qt, QTimer, QPoint
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor, QKeyEvent, QMouseEvent, QPainter, QPen, QPaintEvent, QPainterPath, QBrush
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        screenWidth = 1920
        screenHeight = 1080
        self.gX = []
        self.gY = []
        self.framesShowPerSecond = 30
        self.age = 0
        self.maxAge = 500
        self.windowWidth = 1920
        self.windowHeight = 1080
        self.isRunning = True
        self.angle = -90
        self.clockCounterVariable = 0
        self.milliseconds = 0
        self.seconds = 0
        self.minutes = 0
        self.hours = 0
        self.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.setGeometry((screenWidth - self.windowWidth) // 2, (screenHeight - self.windowHeight) // 2, self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(20, 20, 20);font-size:20px;")
        self.xCounter = 0
        self.clock = QTimer(self)
        self.graphicTimer = QTimer(self)
        self.clock.timeout.connect(self.clockCounter)
        self.graphicTimer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.graphicTimer.start(round((1/self.framesShowPerSecond)*1000))
        self.clock.start(10)
        self.show()

    def clockCounter(self) -> None:
        if self.clockCounterVariable % 10 == 0:
            x = self.xCounter
            y = randint(0, 100)
            self.xCounter += 1
            self.gX.append(x - 0.5)
            self.gX.append(x + 0.5)
            self.gY.append(y)
            self.gY.append(y)
        self.clockCounterVariable += 1

    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QKeyEvent) -> super:
        key = QKeyEvent.key(event)
        if key == 112 or key == 80: # P/p
            if self.isRunning:
                print("pause process")
                self.isRunning = False
                self.clock.stop()
                self.graphicTimer.stop()
            else:
                print("continue process")
                self.isRunning = True
                self.clock.start(1000)
                self.graphicTimer.start(round((1/self.framesShowPerSecond)*1000))
        elif (key == 115) or (key == 83): # S/s
            self.closeWindow()
        self.update()
        return super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> super:
        if event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            if self.isRunning:
                print("pause process")
                self.isRunning = False
                self.clock.stop()
                self.graphicTimer.stop()
            else:
                print("continue process")
                self.isRunning = True
                self.clock.start(1000)
                self.graphicTimer.start(round((1/self.framesShowPerSecond)*1000))
        return super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent) -> super:
        self.milliseconds = self.clockCounterVariable
        self.seconds, self.milliseconds = divmod(self.milliseconds, 100)
        self.minutes, self.seconds = divmod(self.seconds, 60)
        self.hours, self.minutes = divmod(self.minutes, 60)
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 128, 20),  1, Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine))
        painter.drawText(QRectF(35, 30, 400, 30), Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft, "{:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d}".format(self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds, self.milliseconds))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(20, 20, 20),  -1, Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(20, 20, 160), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        barrier = QRectF(1920//2-25, 1080//2-25-40, 50, 20)
        painter.drawRect(barrier)
        painter.translate(QPoint(1920//2, 1080//2))
        painter.rotate(self.angle)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(200, 200, 200, 50), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        r = 200
        a = 40
        b = a * 2
        rect = QRectF(-r/2, -r/2, r, r)
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.arcTo(rect, -a, b)
        path.closeSubpath()
        if path.contains(barrier):
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(200, 20, 20, 50), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        else:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(20, 200, 20, 50), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawPath(path)
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.arcTo(rect, -a+90, b)
        path.closeSubpath()
        if path.contains(barrier):
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(200, 20, 20, 50), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        else:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(20, 200, 20, 50), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawPath(path)
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.arcTo(rect, -a-90, b)
        path.closeSubpath()
        if path.contains(barrier):
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(200, 20, 20, 50), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        else:
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(20, 200, 20, 50), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawPath(path)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(160, 20, 20), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(30, 0)
        path.lineTo(-30, -15)
        path.lineTo(-10, 0)
        path.lineTo(-30, 15)
        path.closeSubpath()
        painter.drawPath(path)
        painter.end()
        self.angle += 1
        if self.angle == 360:
            self.angle = 0
        return super().paintEvent(event)

    def closeWindow(self) -> None:
        print("closing window ...")
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(argv)
    window = Window()
    exit(App.exec())
```

how should I do this purpose?

I want to detect collisions between some slices of a circle and rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many issues, but your main problem is caused by two factors:

1. you are using [`contains()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainterpath.html#contains-1), which "Returns `true` if the given rectangle **is inside** the path"; you should use [`intersects()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainterpath.html#intersects) instead;
2. the "barrier" is created using the final, *absolute* coordinates, while all the other paths are in *relative* coordinates, since you are translating the painter;
3. the painter is rotated, not the objects;

The result is that even using `contains()`, it will never work, since the objects are too far apart:

- `barrier = QRectF(1920//2-25, 1080//2-25-40, 50, 20)` which is `935, 475, 50, 20`;
- `rect = QRectF(-r/2, -r/2, r, r)` which is `-100, -100, 200, 200`;

As you can see, they are not even *close*.

Not only: it wouldn't work anyway because the paths never consider the rotation, as you applied it to the painter.

The *proper* solution requires to:

- always use the same coordinate reference;
- apply the transformations (translation and rotation) *to the objects* and then detect the possible collision;

In order to do that, we can use [Qtransform](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtransform.html) along with its [`map()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtransform.html#map-8) function, which returns a *new* transformed path.

Note that QTransform is always aligned to the `0, 0` coordinate, so in order to properly rotate around a different reference point, you must:

1. translate the transform to the reference point;
2. apply the rotation;
3. translate *back* using the negative of the reference point;

Here is an improved version of your code:

```py
    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent) -> super:
        secs, ms = divmod(self.clockCounterVariable, 100)
        mins, secs = divmod(secs, 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 128, 20),  1, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawText(QRectF(35, 30, 400, 30), Qt.AlignLeft, 
            "{:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d} : {:02d}".format(hours, mins, secs, ms))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(20, 20, 20),  -1, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(20, 20, 160), Qt.SolidPattern))

        
        reference = QPointF(1920 / 2, 1080 / 2)
        barrier = QRectF(reference.x() - 25, reference.y() - 65, 50, 20)
        painter.drawRect(barrier)

        r = 200
        a = 40
        b = a * 2
        rect = QRectF(-r/2, -r/2, r, r).translated(reference)

        collideBrush = QBrush(QColor(200, 20, 20, 50))
        normalBrush = QBrush(QColor(20, 200, 20, 50))

        reference = rect.center()
        transform = QTransform()
        transform.translate(reference.x(), reference.y())
        transform.rotate(self.angle)
        transform.translate(-reference.x(), -reference.y())

        for deltaAngle in (0, 90, -90):
            path = QPainterPath(reference)
            path.arcTo(rect, -a + deltaAngle, b)
            path.closeSubpath()
            path = transform.map(path)
            if path.intersects(barrier):
                painter.setBrush(collideBrush)
            else:
                painter.setBrush(normalBrush)
            painter.drawPath(path)

        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(160, 20, 20)))
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(30, 0)
        path.lineTo(-30, -15)
        path.lineTo(-10, 0)
        path.lineTo(-30, 15)
        path.closeSubpath()
        path.translate(rect.center())
        painter.drawPath(transform.map(path))

        self.angle = (self.angle + 1) % 360
```

Note that there are other issues with your code, for instance:

- use `event.key()`, not `QKeyEvent.key(event)`;
- I don't know where you got those `112` and `115` values for the keys, but they are wrong: `event.key()` returns an enum that is **always** the same for letter keys, no matter the modifiers (which you must check with `event.modifier()`); just check the key against `Qt.Key.Key_P` or `Qt.Key.Key_S` and it will work for both lower and upper cases;
- event handlers don't return anything, those `return` when calling the base implementations are useless;
- you are creating instance attributes that are only used within the scope of a function: setting `self.milliseconds`, `self.seconds` etc. is quite pointless for this case; if you *do* need those values outside of that function, they should certainly **not** be computed in the `paintEvent()`, because if the window is hidden it will not be called: instead, compute those values in `clockCounter` and call `self.update()`;

Finally, when dealing with complex graphics, implementing everything with the basic QPainter is not really effective, and normally results in making things more complex (and prone to errors and bugs) than necessary. Consider using the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/graphicsview.html) instead.

Comment: thank you a lot, there were a lot of things to learn from your answer to me.
112 and 115 are the ASCII values of the keys, but using `Qt.Key` is obviously better for simplicity and understanding of the code.
I am slightly strange with the `Qtransform` and the `map()` functions and I must read the documentation.
again thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

### For the collision between a circle and an oriented rectangle

find the closest point on the rectangle to the circle -> easy because the rectangle is oriented on the grid.

check the distance of this point to the circle center.

general example

```
circle_x, circle_y = 1,1 #circle centre
circle_r = 3 #circle radius

rect_xmin = 2 #quadrilateral left x limit
rect_xmax = 4 #quadrilateral right x limit
rect_ymin = 3 #quadrilateral bottom y limit
rect_ymax = 3 #quadrilateral top y limit


if circle_x < rect_xmin:
    point_x = rect_xmin
elif circle_x > rect_xmax:
    point_x = rect_xmax
else:
    point_x = circle_x

if circle_y < rect_ymin:
    point_y = rect_ymin
elif circle_y > rect_ymax:
    point_y = rect_ymax
else:
    point_y = circle_y
    
print("collision", (circle_x-point_x)**2 + (circle_y-point_y)**2 < circle_r**2, "at", (point_x, point_y))
```

maybe you could use (point_x, point_y) to check the angle of the location of the collision to find the quadrant?

Comment: The issue was caused by the fact that the OP used two coordinate systems (absolute and relative), so no collision detection was possible. Besides, the OP requires to know the collision with **arcs**, not full circles.